# Why can't I login to my "network sites"?

Tags: multisite

I have a Multi Site install that looks like this:

main.dev.domain.com

testsite.dev.domain.com

dcdc.dev.domain.com

on main.dev.domain.com I can login as admin and do all the regular stuff (like change themes) but then when I go to the dashboards of the other sites, all I get is a login box where NOTHING works. I know in Network Admin I need to add the user to that domain and I've done that and the sites under "users" I see that user is enabled. However, when I go to testsite.dev.domain.com/wp-admin (the way to get to the dashboard of the site) I get a login box where no username and password work (not the one that I made when I setup the new site or admin which I enabled).

Is this by design? I finally changed the theme but I had to do it in edit site/setting where there is a long list of options and I just pasted in the theme path in there somewhere.

Comment: Are you using the `wp-config.php` network settings you were given. My guess is that the config file is confused by the domain and your cookies aren't being set correctly.

Comment: I ended up fixing this issue but I asked this so long ago I forgot what I did. I'll go back and look and see if I can remember.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing and configuring the "[WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)" plugin? There's an excellent [tutorial available](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/). Please note you have to manually install this plugin.